# Java - Prefix to Postfix using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

so I am in the middle of a data structures course and we have been tasked with making a recursive solution to a prefix (-+ABC) problem and converting it into a postfix (AB+C-) solution. I feel like I'm 70% there...just missing that little something.

The outputString is then returned and written to a .txt file. I know this part works due to past labs I have worked with.

The code provided returns BCBCABCBCBCABC+ABC when it should in theory return AB+C-

```
 public static boolean operator(char o) {

    return o == '+' || o == '-' || o == '*' || o == '/' || o == '$';
}

public static String preToPost(String s) {

    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    // System.out.println(c);
    char ch = c[0];
    //System.out.println(ch);

    char[] cMinusFront = new char[s.length() - 1];

    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        cMinusFront[k++] = c[i];

    }

    s = String.valueOf(cMinusFront);
    System.out.println(s);
    String a;
    String b;
    String outputString = null;

    if (s.length() == 1) {
        return outputString;
    }

    if (operator(ch)) {
        a = preToPost(s);

    } else {
        a = s.substring(0, 0);
    }
    if (operator(ch)) {
        b = preToPost(s);
    } else {
        b = s.substring(0, 0);
    }

    outputString = a;
    outputString = outputString.concat(b);
    outputString = outputString.concat(String.valueOf(cMinusFront));

    return outputString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static boolean isOperator(char ch) {
    return ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/';
}

static String preToPost(StringReader input) throws IOException {
    int ch = input.read();
    if (ch == -1)
        return "";
    else if (isOperator((char)ch))
        return preToPost(input) + preToPost(input) + (char)ch;
    else
        return "" + (char)ch;
}

static String preToPost(String input) throws IOException {
    return preToPost(new StringReader(input));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(preToPost("*-+ABC"));
}
```

output:

```
AB+C-*
```